# VS Extension: Git branch change event?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

Is there an event available to extensions that fires when the current branch changes? I need to retrieve data from GitHub any time this happens.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. Also explain in detail what you mean by "when the current branch changes" and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I set up a FileSystemWatcher on %projectroot%.git\HEAD that handles the Created event, since Git deletes and recreates on branch change. Hot tip: set EnableRaisingEvents AFTER the object is instantiated with the path parameter. Otherwise you'll get an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: This probably works in more than 99% of all cases, but it is possible that `.git` is a text file, not a directory, containing `gitdir: <path to git directory>`. This is the case for example when using [worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).